# Drupal 7 - Node Revisions per Role

Tags: drupal, roles, revision

I have created a new role '**news contributor**'.
I have created a new content type '**news**'.

The '**news contributor**' role has permissions enabled to **view, revert, delete revisions**.
However, this setting also gives them access to view, revert, delete revisions on ALL nodes.

[image]

How can i restrict node revisions on specific content types based on user role?

The '**news contributor**' should only be able to tinker with revisions for the '**news**' content type and nothing else.

At the moment they have access to revision any node which is undesirable.

Has anyone had this issue before and, how did you resolve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is not possible in drupal core. To get around this is to disable core  revision and use the [Revisioning](https://www.drupal.org/project/revisioning) module instead. You can grant permission to a specific role to publish while other roles can have the ability to create revisions as this user pointed out: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/124385/32276